# How to include version attribute in output when marshalling

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Below is the valid xml .

```
<Input xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="some.xsd" 
       version="V16.2" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SITE>com</SITE>
<LANGUAGE>SV</LANGUAGE>
</Input>
```

The XML which I got from XSD to JAXB then XML using Marshallar is:

```
<Input xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="some.xsd" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <SITE>com</SITE>
    <LANGUAGE>SV</LANGUAGE>    
</Input>
```

SO the problem is that `version="V16.2"` is missing in the second generated XML, so the consuming code throws an error.

My Marshaller property

```
Marshaller marshaller= jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "some.xsd");
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to include a `version` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the version value on your Input object before the marshaling? Guessing without seeinign your java beans but the version attribute is mapped to a field of your Input element implementation.